# Не выводит текст после return

Tags: javascript

Я написал такую функцию, которая возвращает и `alert`'ит сумму двух аргументов:

```js
function getSum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
    alert(a + b);
}

var c = getSum(2, 3);
```

Почему результат не выводится?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому, что всё после `return` не выполняется, просто поменяйте местами строки кода:

```
function getSum(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
    return a + b;
}

var c = getSum(2, 3);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!